# MySpace Login URL?

Tags: myspace

I want to allow users log-into MySpace directly from a URL?

I see that when MySpace submits its login form it goes to:

https://secure.myspace.com/index.cfm?fuseaction=login.process

But I need to tack on all the hidden parameters as well as the login text box and password text box.

Does anybody have this done already?

I know I would do something like: https://secure.myspace.com/index.cfm?fuseaction=login.process&ctl00_ctl00_cpMain_cpMain_LoginBox_Email_Textbox_Label=&ctl00$ctl00$cpMain$cpMain$LoginBox$Password_Textbox=

Answer (score 1):

Considering the security implications of that, I hope it cannot be done.

But you can try grabbing all the form elements / form tag & input 's etc and change the form's action attribute to the fully qualified absolute path.

```
<form action="https://secure.myspace.com/index.cfm?fuseaction=login.process" method="post">
```

Comment: Yeah, security would be interesting security wise. probably a bad move to allow. . I was playing around thinking I could build a simple portal to allow people to log0in to multiple social networking sites at once and work with their profiles, etc.

Comment: Toddly, I built a site like that once, and almost got sued by facebook, so be careful.

Comment: I thought Myspace and Facebook used OpenId now?

Comment: @Toddly: Well, first off, I was using their logo next to the login without their permission (illegal), and they were not ok with me becoming a portal for people to login to their website, even though I was only using static .html pages for the login. They seemed afraid that I could just change it really quickly and steal the user/pass of any of the people that used the site. When my site got hit by digg, later that day they contacted me.